# python reverse number [missing zero characters]

Tags: python, string, reverse

While I'm working with strings I have noticed a problem and the problem is here

When I try to reverse a number using string reverse function in python I have got not entire reversed number

example:

```
 input   36800   //int num=36800
 after reverisng //num=reverse(str(num))
 output  863  *****but I need to get 00863
```

Why last zero's are trimmed Can i know the reason.

Comment: try use [::-1], for example str(num)[::-1]

Comment: What is the reverse function you are using?

Comment: maybe because you simply can not use in Python integers starting with zeros...

Comment: Don't call int on the result if you want to keep the leading zeros.

Comment: You mixed int with string. Output string would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your reverse function is returning an integer, but you cannot have an integer that prints as `00863`, instead you can have a string that does that.

```
>>> num = 36800
>>> str(num)[::-1]
'00863'
>>> int(str(num)[::-1])
863
```